# Can I draw something with a 'soul' if it's for school?

Tags: halal-haram, soul, drawing, school

I had read an answer from another post which stated that I may not draw something with a 'soul' like a human. I have many school projects which require drawing a human or living thing. Also, am I allowed to draw human organs or characteristics like a heart or talking?

Answer (score 1):

In the name of God, the Most Merciful, the Most Kind.

**Answer:**

**Your question:** am I allowed to draw human organs or characteristics like a heart or talking?

Yes, you can draw any unanimated things, because

> ”Narrated Abdullah ibn 'Umar (d. 73H) radiallahu 'anhu: God’s Messenger sallallahu 'alayhi wa sallam said, "Those who make these images (suwar) will be punished on the Day of Resurrection, and it will be said to them, make alive what you have created." [Al-Bukhari 7/541, no.835; Muslim, 3/160, no. 5268]

In here it talks about only animated things, but if you have to, you can make something  that is unanimated such as heart or any organ, cars etc...

> It was narrated from Ibn ‘Abbaas (may God be pleased with him) that a man came to him and said: O Ibn ‘Abbaas, I am a man who earns a living from what my hands make, and I make these images. Ibn ‘Abbaas said: I will not tell you anything except that which I heard from the Messenger of God (blessings and peace of God be upon him). I heard him say: “Whoever makes an image in this world, God will punish him until he breathes the soul into it, and he will never be able to do that.” The man was very afraid and his face turned yellow. He [Ibn ‘Abbaas] said: Woe to you! If you must do that, then (make images of) these trees and everything that has no soul. Narrated by al-Bukhaari (2225) and Muslim (2110).

So in here we learn that if you want for example, human organs, then it is permissible.

---

**References:**

1. http://sunnahonline.com/library/fiqh-and-sunnah/130-ahadith-concerning-taswir-pictures
2. https://islamqa.info/en/70497

Comment: References: http://sunnahonline.com/library/fiqh-and-sunnah/130-ahadith-concerning-taswir-pictures and https://islamqa.info/en/70497